# private sub before sheet generation VBA

Tags: excel, vba, private

I have a Macro where from one table in a sheet, other sheets are generated.

Into one of the generated sheets I want to add some ActiveX controls. But they work with private Subs, and I dont know how to program the ActiveX controls private subs because they do not exists in a begining.

Is there a solution to the problem?

Is not possible to write the PrivateSubs before the sheets are created?

Is there some vba practice I don't know to achive this?

Comment: There is an event that fires on sheet creation, but it's not clear what you are actually trying to do.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.newsheet

Comment: I'm quite new to xl vba, I don't know well what are the private subs, I have only seen that they are writen in the Sheet module. My Macro already generates a new_sheet. I can add an OLE Object into the new_sheet (I guess). But I cannot program it because the new_sheet doesnt exists in a begining. What I want to achieve is to set up a form in excel with controls so the user can navigate through the information.

Comment: You can definitely add and manipulate controls after the sheet is created.

Comment: Do you have some example or source where I can learn? I can't find it. The only resources I found shows that the controls are programmed in the sheet module as a private sub. (And the problem is that I can't program it before the sheet is created).

Comment: The control has to run a Macro when selected. I want to use a drop Down list

Comment: Use a hidden sheet as a template, then you can have all the controls and event handler subs all ready to go. Just copy the hidden sheet, then fill in the data.

Comment: A template sheet is probably the simplest way for you to go about this.  It is possible to create controls and edit their code and events dynamically (using CreateEventProc and InsertLines, for instance) or to use class modules to abstract code and events for duplication, but a template sheet is likely to be the simplest way.  Check this for dynamic code creation (https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/programmatically-inserting-a-worksheet-change-event.428213/, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createeventproc-method-vba-add-in-object-model)

Comment: and this for a couple of examples of worksheet controls in class modules (https://jkp-ads.com/articles/ControlHandler02.asp, https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/checkboxes-and-worksheet_change-event.102373/).  I believe it is possible to abstract an entire sheet the same way, but it sounds like you could probably just create a class module based on a specific control.